# UIAction Sheet and Alert trouble

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uialertview, uiactionsheet

Hello, I am new to Xcode and programming in iOS.
I am having some troubles in my actionsheet and my alert, have to press twice to work.
Its also says this:
"Presenting actionsheet clipped by its superview". Some controls might not respond to touches. On iPhone try -[UIActionSheet showFromTabBar:] or -[UIActionSheet showFromToolbar:] instead of -[UIActionSheet showInView:].

```
{
    UIActionSheet   *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"¿?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Send" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

any help will be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You need to put it in the tabbar (or toolbar) so instead of:

```
 [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

do

```
 [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

Answer (score 1):

If your application is using a navigation bar (and not a tool bar) on the screen where you want to present the `UIActionSheet`, try to present it on the tool bar of the navigation controller.

This would also present the action sheet even if you have hidden your navigation controller's toolbar.

`[myActionSheet showInView:self.navigationController.toolbar]`

Comment: This doesn't support landscape

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I resolved using `[actionSheet showInView:self.parentViewController.view];` instead of self.view , if you used tabbar or naviatinbar

Comment: dobiho, your way may work but you really should do what they recommend by using the `showFromTabBar`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This method is also working, it hides **"Presenting action sheet clipped by its superview"** warning.

```
[actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
```

Comment: This doesn't support landscape